# BIRT report output not visible in "view report as PDF" option

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, birt

I have recently installed BIRT in a 64 bit windows 8 machine. When I view a report in HTML output or any other output the report is visible just fine. But when I chose to view it as PDF , a blank page opens with a small cross on top left corner and nothing else. (attaching screen shot)
[image: Screen shot when clicked on "view as pdf"]

I tried opening the same report on other machine (Windows 7) with BIRT "view as PDF" and it works fine.

I have checked opening other pdf files on my machine, they open perfectly OK. Is there any other setting I need to do in other to make the pdf output of report visible or is it a bug with windows 8  64 bit version.

**Version Details**

BIRT : Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-091

**Adobe**

Version 11.0.3

---

Thanks for your help...

Comment: It would also be interesting to see *which* browser is actually used, e.g. if you're viewing the report as HTML. Is it MSIE, Firefox, Chrome, ...? And since you're on 65 bit, also: is that browser a 32bit or 64bit program? I reckon the PDF/browser integration only works with the 32bit version.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a moderately complex report. Try to narrow the possiblities by creating a very simple report with only a lable "test" and see if it opens in PDF on your 64 bit windows 8 machine. If it does then you know, there is something in your report blocking the PDF, if it does not then you have pretty much proven it is a bug with windows 8 64 bit version.

If your simple report works, you will want to begin recreating your complex report one peice at a time, and testing it, with each new element. When it stops working you will know what breaks it.

Comment: That is a conclusion that I myself would make, except that I get the same problem with Windows 7.  The same problem happens with a simple report, unfortunately.  I've tried re-installing adobe acrobat reader as well.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Neil, Your problem is slightly different then the OP, they have it working on windows 7.  I am running Windows 7, 64 bit with BIRT 4.2 and it looks like Adobe Reader XI.  Not having a problem with PDF, I am actually creating single page PDFs several times a day and emailing them as attachments.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I tried with a simple report with only a label inside. Still facing the issue.

Comment: @Jimit That is a bummer;  Presumably the simple also has issues on Window 7?  We know that my set up is very similar to the scenario and mine works, so it is not a huge bug. It is relatively easy to get different BIRT versions, so unless you are running BRIT 4.3 get 4.3 and a version earlier then what you are running now.  Once you get it working you just have to keep problem solving until you figure out what is out of alignment in your setup.

Comment: @Neil, sometime fonts can cause issues with BIRT reports going to PDF.  If you used a custom font, and PDF does not have it, they may be the cause.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't think so, but I appreciate the effort anyway.  Might be one of those things that you simply have to circumnavigate.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the solution that worked for me was to:
- click on Window->Preferences
- click General->Web Browser in the navigation pane
- select use external web browser and pick the external browser of choice
- hit apply, ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by installing the Adobe Reader. Previously I had only an alternative PDF reader (Foxit) installed. After I installed the original Adobe Reader, the "View Report As PDF" menu item worked as desired. Setting the Adobe Reader as the default PDF viewer was NOT required.

Maybe re-installing the Adobe Reader in the latest version and with default settings does the trick for you?