# How to avoid data being cut when presenting a BIRT report as PDF?

Tags: pdf, scripting, report, birt

After exporting report in PDF format I realized that a few rows were hidden. As you can see in the image:

[image: PDF Format]

Notice that the 1st row in the second page is not the next row fetched by the data set, which should actually be 10 January 15 03:00.

Also, there's no Page Break, instead the default layout comes from the Master Page which is US letter.

I've been trying different solutions for this problem and after checking 
[M Williams](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/25695-data-is-cutting-in-export-to-pdf/) and [James Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607037/birt-report-output-not-visible-in-view-report-as-pdf-option) suggestions (among others) I still couldn't find it.

Perhaps Dominique could help? Dom?

Comment: It looks like you data is sorting by the field ESME

Comment: Hi James, I made sure the data was ordered by "period" (Date & Time) when editing the data set query. Thanks for your comment and the previous suggestions!

Comment: The large blank space we can see below  this table suggests there is a fixed margin or something like that which prevents all rows to be displayed. What is the value of the "Page break interval" property of the table? By default it is 40, try to decrease it until all rows are displayed in PDF. Otherwise you need to find out which element of the report has a fixed height or margin, This blank space might also be due to a property of the master page such margins and footer size.

Comment: Hi Dominique, that is exactly what I was looking for. Please, post your comment as an answer. Just so you know, I changed the "page break interval" property of the table to 24 (hours). Works like a charm. (For new people) To see the Page Break Interval click on the table symbol that appears when you hover over the table and go to the Property Editor, select Page Break on the left side and change Page Break Interval as you wish.

Comment: As an observation, this **seems** to be set to 40 as default to fit an A4 or US Letter  Portrait orientation. When I changed the orientation of the page as a whole the table remained with that value. Be aware of this problem when changing orientation or type in your master page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large blank space we can see below this table suggests there is a fixed margin or something like that which prevents all rows to be displayed. What is the value of the "Page break interval" property of the table? By default it is 40, try to decrease it until all rows are displayed in PDF. Otherwise you need to find out which element of the report has a fixed height or margin, This blank space might also be due to a property of the master page such margins and footer size